# What happens to created elements that don't get appended in Meteor? Do they sit/hog memory?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor/Javascript, what happens to elements created by...

```
document.createElement('div')
```

but never appended to DOM?

Do they sit in memory and hog resources?

---or----

Do they get auto removed when template gets destroyed?

Comment: You never insert it into the page? Then it will be destroyed when you've got no reference to it anymore, like all other objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm often curious about how all the things I don't see work. Like this one.

Comment: I'm not an expert in garbage collection in JavaScript, but JavaScript is a language where you shouldn't concern about destroying objects/releasing memory. The language itself is responsible for doing this. However, I don't know if it's specified anywhere how (when) the garbage collection should work, but if you're dealing with giant objects, you need to take this into account despite all. David Glasser (a guy working at Meteor) has written a short post about it: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/13/an-interesting-kind-of-javascript-memory-leak